# How to run protractor?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, gruntjs, protractor

I'm very new to protractor. I am running this in Windows command line.

I followed the this tutorial https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

I sucessfully run `npm install -g protractor`

I don't know how to run this `node_modules/protractor/bin/install_selenium_standalone`

If I run this straight away in command line. I am getting this error `'node_modules\protractor\bin\install_selenium_standalone' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Help me to run this sucessfully. As well as this command `./selenium/start`

I am waiting for the prompt response......

Comment: If you cd to the `bin` directory, do you see the `install_selenium_standalone` file?

Comment: And if you run it inside the directory, what error do you receive?

Comment: You mean: npm\node_modules\protractor\bin>install_selenium_standalone  If I run this way, I'm getting error as 'install_selenium_standalone' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I had to install globaly first - npm install -g protractor

Answer (score 7):

An alternate solution to the selenium standalone server is to use the binary that protractor gives us:

```
$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

This will download the files with selenium and make a start script

```
$ ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
```

This will start the standalone server.

A great article for Protractor setup and use:

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/practical-protractor.html

Comment: While starting the webdriver-manager, can we specify the port at which it need to run on? By default it runs on 4444 but i would like it to run at say 1243.

Comment: I was using the webdriver-manager update command and found that it was not successfully downloading the selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar.  It just put a file in place of 0kb.

Answer (score 5):

Install node first and then use **node** ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Comment: Could you expand on this a little please?

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7 when no other solution would.

Answer (score 3):

I was using the webdriver-manager update command and found that it was not successfully downloading the selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar.

I manually downloaded the file and put it where it should be.

You may also have to install java and put it in your PATH variable as per https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/369

..and don't forget to re-open the node.js command prompt after changing your PATH variable.

Comment: Same issue here. My network was blocking the jar file to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can install selenium standalone using "node install_selenium_standalone", if you directly write install_selenium_standalone on the command prompt it wont run, to install it with node you will need to have node installer installed on ur system its set up is very simple you can get the MSI from nodejs office website http://nodejs.org/download/

Let me know if you are still facing this error.