# Angularjs trying to run protractor

Tags: angularjs

I am completing this [angularjs tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03)

on step 3 they tell you to run the protractor by `npm run protractor`

when i do this inside the angular-phonecat folder nothing happens:

[image: Nothing happens]
I have run the `npm install`  and `npm run update-webdriver` command as directed beforehand.

Whats more i downloaded the android seed project and copied the code from step 3 in the tutorial to the controlers.js index.html and scenerios.js

When i run the protractor I get the following error (after my browser opens):

```
> angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor C:\wamp\www\angularSite
> protractor test/protractor-conf.js

Starting selenium standalone server...
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.0.7.22:55840/wd/hub

C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\
lib\webdriver\promise.js:1549
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:8000/app/index.ht
ml : retries looking for angular exceeded
    at assertAngularOnPage (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\lib\
protractor.js:668:13)
    at C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-web
driver\lib\goog\base.js:1178:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\nod
e_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:14
45:20)
    at notify (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\sele
nium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:328:12)
    at notifyAll (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\s
elenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:297:7)
    at fulfill (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\sel
enium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:402:7)
    at Object.webdriver.promise.asap (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:678:5)
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\nod
e_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:14
56:25)
    at notify (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\sele
nium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:328:12)
    at notifyAll (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\s
elenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:297:7)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:267:15)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.executeAsyncScript (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:507:15
)
    at Protractor.get (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\lib\protr
actor.js:675:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\test\e2e\scenarios.js:7:11)
    at jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:907:21)
    at jasmine.Env.describe (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:892:15)
    at describe (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\mi
nijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:652:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\angularSite\test\e2e\scenarios.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6002
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\angularSite
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\angularSite\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here is the contents of my log file (just in case) npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'protractor' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.3
3 info using node@v0.10.26
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'preprotractor', 'protractor', 'postprotractor' ]
6 info preprotractor angular-seed@0.0.0
7 info protractor angular-seed@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info angular-seed@0.0.0 Failed to exec protractor script
10 error angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
10 error Exit status 8
11 error Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 protractor script.
11 error This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
11 error not with npm itself.
11 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11 error     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
11 error You can get their info via:
11 error     npm owner ls angular-seed
11 error There is likely additional logging output above.
12 error System Windows_NT 6.0.6002
13 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
14 error cwd C:\wamp\www\angularSite
15 error node -v v0.10.26
16 error npm -v 1.4.3
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I run windows vista x64 on my machine if that helps at all.

Comment: I have the same error. What is even weirder is that it was working well last week!

Comment: I have the same error and I have most definitely not forgotten to npm start.

Comment: I also have.. 'error code ELIFECYCLE', but 'error Exit status 1'.  I am using npm@1.4.9 node@v0.10.28 otherwise the same really.  Suppose I'll have to look into protractor if not answered soon.

Answer (score 12):

I have encountered this when I forgot to run my webserver. You can solve it by simply running `npm start` in a separate shell. Protractor does not do this for you.

Comment: It yields no effect. nmp start works yet the results are still the same.

Comment: Error message is not very clear, but when I run the web server and run protractor on another DOS shell, it works fine.

Comment: This one works for me. Since it seems not to work for everyone, here are some details about my setup: Angular-seed project. Runing npm start to start webserver, runing 'protractor e2e-test/protractor.conf.js' to start tests

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. For me, the problem was that I had not ran "bower install". Try running "bower install" and then "npm run protractor".

Comment: I get: 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: you should install bower then before you try the "bower install". do:
"npm install -g bower" (or without the -g if you want it local)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get to a different error by updating the karma and karma-jasmine version in package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~0.12",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0",
```

I then fixed something else:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772014/329367

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and installing a Java Runtime fixed it for me.

The Selenium driver requires java.

Be sure to open a new console after installing so java is added to the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Angular could not be found on the page
```

means protractor could probably not find ng-app on the page.

```
<html ng-app="yourAppName">
```

check your html page. some people had problems with this when the ng-app tag was not inside the outest of html elements. at  level might be sufficient. (or protractor could not access your page at all).

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with versions in `package.json`. I've tried the examples from [Jonh Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa) and, with my code, extracted from the AngularJS tutorial, it didn't work.
I've taken the `package.json` from the AngularJS tutorial, removed that of Papa, moved `node_modules` to `node_modules__` and run `npm install` and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the issue for me:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder

2. Run `npm install`